# When does a Python Numpy array declaration get no arguments?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, flycapture

I have a camera connected to my computer that produces 16bit grayscale images. I am importing them with the camera manufacturer's proprietary software and then insert them into a numpy array.

```
imObj = fc2.Image()
frame = np.array(c.retrieve_buffer(imObj))
```

This casts the array as a uint8.  If I try to add the dtype parameter to the array declaration:

```
frame = np.array(c.retrieve_buffer(imObj), dtype = np.uint16)
```

I get the following output:

```
typeError: __array__() takes no arguments (1 given)
```

Anybody know what is causing this?

EDIT:
I am using pyflycapture2.  I don't know how to call or set the Image class attributes.

Comment: What's the type of `c.retrieve_buffer(imObj)`?

Comment: type is 'flycapture2.Image'

Answer (score 3):

It seems you are possibly using `pyflycapture2`, which does not seem to have an `__array__` hook capable of recasting the data.

Instead, its `__array__` hook chooses the `dtype` appropriate to the image.  That is, it returns a `uint8` based array if the underlying format is `PIXEL_FORMAT_MONO8` and a `uint16` based array when the format is `PIXEL_FORMAT_MONO16`.

It might be worth checking that the image format (`c.retrieve_buffer(imObj).img.format`) is what you think it is?

Comment: In other words, `np.array` is trying to call `c.retrieve_buffer(imObj).__array__(dtype)`.  If that object were an `ndarray` it would work, since `A.__array__(np.uint16)` works for an ordinary array.